# Direct permalink (object_id) to posts on the new facebook Timeline profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

How do you link directly to a wall post under the Facebook Timeline view of things?

With the old Facebook profiles, you can use Firebug (a Firefox add-on) to look at the wall post, and get the `object_id`.

With a Timeline profile, there is no `object_id`, rather there are:

- `contentid` (sometimes negative)
- `contextwindowstart`
- `contextwindowend`

None of them work when placed in a direct link URL, e.g. `http://www.facebook.com/[profile-username]/posts/[object_id]`.

Comment: This seems (somewhat) related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80998/how-can-i-get-the-permalink-for-every-facebook-post

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do to link directly to a post from the timeline is to click on the timestamp that shows you when it was posted.

That permalink will take you to a page featuring just that update and any comments attached to it.