# How can I get the permalink for every Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

When I want to share a Facebook post on another site, I need to search the embed code (or share the post on my timeline) every time, and this is really uncomfortable.

So I would like something similar to this:
[image]

"Get link" would be an actual link for the post.

Is that possible?

Comment: This post seems (somewhat) related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24229/direct-permalink-object-id-to-posts-on-the-new-facebook-timeline-profiles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date/time of the post is actually a link of the post.

Comment: Thanks for that!
Now I need to add this menu point to drop down menu somehow becouse I can esay forget that point.

Comment: @Pequin: That's true for a lot of sites. For instance, the permalink to this comment is the time it was posted (e.g., "1 day ago").

Comment: It is greyed, so it did not seem to me as evident :-) .